# I am getting the error saying to refresh the page, whenever I click on submit button in the lightning component salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce

[image: The error is as shown in the picture when I click on submit.]

Below is the code supporting the following error .The record is saved but it asks me to refresh the page to reflect in the list. Please check the image for the error. Everything is working fine but for some reason its popping up this error.

```xml
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="newFlat" type="Object"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="newFlatError" type="String"/>
   <aura:attribute name="flatRecord" type="Object" />
    <force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
                    targetRecord="{!v.newFlat}"
                   targetError="{!v.newFlatError}"
                    targetFields="{!v.flatRecord}"
                    layoutType="FULL"
                     />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:input aura:id="flatField" label="Flat Name" value="{!v.flatRecord.Name}" required="true"/>
    <lightning:input aura:id="flatField" label="Flat Number" value="{!v.flatRecord.Flat_number__c}"/>
    <lightning:input aura:id="flatField" label="Floor" value="{!v.flatRecord.Floor__c}"/>     

    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit"  onclick="{!c.handleSaveFlat}"/> 

</aura:component>
```

```js
 handleSaveFlat : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(helper.validateFlatForm(component)) {
            component.set("v.flatRecord.Building__c",component.get("v.recordId"));
            component.find("forceRecord").saveRecord(function(saveResult){
                if(saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT"){
                    var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast") 
                    resultToast.setParams({
                        "title" : "Saved",
                        "message" : "The record was saved."
                    });
                    resultToast.fire();
                    component.set("v.flatRecord.Name","");
                    component.set("v.flatRecord.Flat_number__c","")
                    component.set("v.flatRecord.Floor__c","")
                }
                else if(saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.")
                }
                else if(saveResult.state ==="ERROR") {
                    console.log("Unknown problem, State:"+saveResult.state+
                                ",error"+JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error was because of mismatch in variable names, as in my code the variable **resultsToast** was used as **resultToast** . Be Careful with such bugs.